# ImportError: cannot import module from scipy.stats using Pingouin

Tags: python, scipy, pingouin

This issue is appearing in a local Jupyter notebook and I'm using Python 3.10

Importing `scipy` and `scipy.stats` is no problem.

```python
import scipy
import scipy.stats
```

However, I'm trying to use the Pingouin library for data analysis and running into issues with the following code:

```python
import pingouin as pg
pg.ttest(x,y,paired=True)

--> 201 from scipy.stats.stats import (_unequal_var_ttest_denom,
    202                                _equal_var_ttest_denom)

ImportError: cannot import name '_unequal_var_ttest_denom' from 'scipy.stats.stats'
(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py)
```

Since Pingouin is SciPy dependent, it's trying to import the required modules and getting stuck on at least one. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling SciPy and Pingouin but am unable to resolve this issue. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is a known [`pingouin` issue](https://github.com/raphaelvallat/pingouin/issues/232).  `pingouin` should not have been importing private names from `scipy`.

Comment: If you need place to work until that issue gets sorted and you don't have security or size of data concerns, I just tested your second block of code (left off your first bock) with pingouin 0.5.0 and scipy 1.7.3 by launching a browser-based Jupyter session served via MyBinder by clicking [here](http://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/pythonista_skewedf/master?filepath=index.ipynb) and running `%pip install pingouin` in a cell before trying your second block of code.